# Problem loading view from postgres

Tags: qgis, postgresql

My problem is loading view table from Postgres.

Here is my view table:

```
SELECT h1.gid, h1.st_buffer
   FROM vmo_buffer_2m h1
   LEFT JOIN vodomjeri h2 ON st_intersects(h1.st_buffer, h2.geom)
  WHERE h2.gid IS NULL;
```

and that works normally in qgis.

When change last row with: `WHERE h2.gid IS NOT NULL;` I can see sql query normally with results in pgAdmin, but adding this view table in qgis show error: `(st_buffer) sql= is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded.`

Answer (score 1):

Hi LEFT JOIN may creates doubles, and gid must be unique for QGIS to handle it as a valid layer. Could you try with a LEFT OUTER JOIN? 
Régis

Comment: When add LEFT OUTER JOIN it alwaws show LEFT JOIN (automatic add from postgre). Cant write OUOTER...

Answer (score 1):

It could by a problem in rows where vodomjeri's gid is not null. Probably it will by a problem with geometries. Could you test validity of geometry by *ST_IsValid* Postgis function. It could be a reason why result of st_intersects is invalid for QGIS.